# How to use GNU ZRTP CPP Library without ccRTP?

Tags: c++, rtp

As the GNU ZRTP CPP (https://github.com/wernerd/ZRTPCPP) is a C++ Implementation of ZRTP protocol. It requires the ccRTP lib for the SRTP/RTP part. But now I have implemented the RTP part, I just want to use the ZRTP part(libzrtpcore). Dose anyone know how to use the ZRTPCPP without the ccRTP?
Any opinions are welcomed! Thanks!!